# Linq To Entities without primitive types

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I need to execute a query with a where clause by comparing a range of int data.

For instance:

```
class RangeClass
{
public int From{get; set;}
public int To {get; set;}
}

void ExecuteQuery()
{
// prepare a list of range data
List<RangeClass> rangeList = new List<Range>();
rangeList .Add(new rangeClass ...
rangeList .Add(new RangeClass ...

DbContext db = new DbContext();

var query = db.Invoice.Where(p => rangeList.Any(x => p.Price >= x.From && p.Price <= x.To)).ToList();
}
```

Obviously, I'm getting NotSupportedExcetpion due to non primitive type I'm using into my query (RangeClass).

Is there some workaround to accomplish my query with Linq To Entities?

@@EDIT

In order to clarify my example, here some informations:

```
RangeClass List (in memory list):
1 - From = 1; To = 10;
2 - From = 20; To = 30;
3 - From = 31; To = 40;
```

Invoice Database Records:

```
1 - Price = 5;
2 - Price = 15;
3 - Price = 20;
```

---

My query should return the first (price 5) and last(price 20)  records of invoice tables, because the second one (price 15) is not between any "record" present in my memory list.

Comment: so you want all the items within the range of all the range lists?

Comment: I think you have to get the lowest and highest values from your `rangeList` and then perform a normal `Where(p=> p.Price >= lowestValue && p.Price <= highestValue)`

Comment: No. What I'm trying to get is, for each Invoice record, get it only if its Price is between From and To property of any range item.

Comment: @bit: now many ranges there will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the range comparison could be replaced with expression like:

```
_.Price >= r1.From && _.Price <= r1.To ||
_.Price >= r2.From && _.Price <= r2.To ||
...
_.Price >= rN.From && _.Price <= rN.To
```

you may build this expression dynamically:

```
static class RangeHelpers
{
    public static IQueryable<T> PropertyFitsAnyRange<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Range> ranges, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyToCompareExpr)
    {
        Expression conditionalExpr = null;

        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            var andExpr = Expression.And(
                Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyToCompareExpr.Body, Expression.Constant(range.From)),
                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyToCompareExpr.Body, Expression.Constant(range.To)));

            conditionalExpr = conditionalExpr == null ? andExpr : Expression.Or(conditionalExpr, andExpr);
        }

        if (conditionalExpr != null)
        {
            query = query
                .Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(conditionalExpr, propertyToCompareExpr.Parameters[0]));
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var invoices = context
    .Invoices
    .PropertyFitsAnyRange(ranges, _ => _.Price);
```

P.S. I believe, that `Invoice.Price` is decimal. If so, the `Range` class definition should be:

```
public class Range
{
    public decimal From { get; set; }
    public decimal To { get; set; }
}
```